# Простой вопрос про циклы в Python

Tags: python, массивы, математика, while

Не совсем понимаю как работает математика внутри цикла `while` в python. Вот у меня есть программный код:

```
def arrayset():
    i = column - 1
    while i != 0:
        NewItemX = CordX + CordStepX
        xarray.append(NewItemX)
        i -= 1
    i = column - 1
    while i != 0:
        NewItemY = CordY + CordStepY
        yarray.append(NewItemY)
        i -= 1
```

И в массив забиваются значения условно 480, 480, 480, 480, 480 в первом случае. И 200, 200, 200, 200, 200 во втором случае, т.е. над `NewItemX` и `NewItemY` производится одна операция со сложением, хотя она внутри цикла `while`...

Comment: а в чем собственно вопрос? не совсем понятно.

Comment: Непонятно, что вы ожидаете от одного и того же действия с одними и теми же значениями - разные результаты? Или если в цикле прибавлять 2+2, то каждый раз будет новый результат?

Comment: и зачем тут 2 `while` когда можно все в 1 делать?

Comment: Хочу чтобы переменные NewItemY и NewItemX изменялись и измененные значения заносились в массив.

Comment: **Как именно** изменялись?

Comment: NewItemY = CordY + CordStepY, чтобы эта операция сложения производилась многократно и чтобы новые значения заносились в массив

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как обычно - при отсутствии точного ТЗ ответ - ХЗ...

Вангую, что вам нужно

```
def arrayset():
    i = column - 1
    NewItemX = CordX
    NewItemY = CordY
    while i != 0:
        NewItemX += CordStepX
        xarray.append(NewItemX)
        NewItemY += CordStepY
        yarray.append(NewItemY)
        i -= 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что `CordX` и `CordStepX` не меняются. Попробуйте так:

```
def arrayset():
    i = column - 1
    NewItemX = CordX
    while i != 0:
        NewItemX += CordStepX
        xarray.append(NewItemX)
        i -= 1
```